# An ExtJS panel/tree/something else that polls

Tags: extjs, ajax-polling

All I want is to display a list of records from a database table that are always up-to-date.

My initial thought was to have a constant ajax call every x seconds checking for updates, but wasnt sure if that was the best way to approach it. I have googled around, and such things as COMET, Ext.Direct, polling, pushing (comet?) have all come up.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think COMET is overkill.

Just a simple JS timer to call your method to refresh the data. No need to over complicate things the simplest solutions is often the best.

Answer (score 0):

I find auto-updating information distracting at any rate of refresh. I would supply a link or button to refresh.

Comment: I agree, but the point of this grid was to appear as if it stayed in sync with the database. Thanks for the comment, I've added in a refresh and pause polling button